# How to check if a response variable exists and has value

Tags: javascript

I have the following post which works and getting expected values. I am only able to enter the **if** block when the value of resp.count is 1 or above. But I want to be able to get into the **if** block even when the value of resp.count is 0. In other words I am just checking that the variable exists and has value. I am trying not to use something like the following.

```
if(resp.count !== undefined){}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this more elegantly? Thanks.

```
return post(api, { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }, data)
  .then((resp) => {
      // count minimum value will be 0. 
      // Able to enter the following IF block only when value of count is 1 or above. 
      if (resp.count) {
        // I want to get in here even if value is 0.
      }
  })
```

Comment: `"count" in resp` is another option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely check if the `resp.count` is more than or equal to zero

```
if (resp.count >= 0) {

}
```

In an event where the count does not exist, it will not satisfy the condition.

```js
console.log(undefined >= 0)
```

Comment: Yes but there is a chance for count to not exist.

Comment: Still, the condition will act correctly  - because undefined is not >= 0

Answer (score 1):

`if (rest.count !== undefined) {}` is literally saying "if the count key is defined, run the following code"

I'm not sure how you would write that any more legibly.

Answer (score 0):

The below should do it.

```
return post(api, { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }, data)
  .then((resp) => {
      // Allow zero and up
      if (resp.count >= 0) {
        // do something...
      }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to walk you'll need to check against [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). I think, you'll want to make sure, that the value is neither `null`, `undefined` nor `""`.

For the first two, you could compare against `!= null` (not `!==` to catch type conversions). If you want to exclude empty string as well, I would follow [SamwellTarly's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852971/how-to-check-if-a-response-variable-exists-and-has-value#comment107664967_60852971) and compare `>= 0`.